# Use different POST inputs everytime to select from database with PHP

Tags: php

HTML (this is just a snippet of a POST form, total form is 25 inputs).

```
<input type="text" name="ram" value"">
<input type="text" name="processor" value"">
<input type="text" name="graphcard" value"">
<input type="text" name="storage" value"">
```

During the processes, all OR some values get defined (e.g. value of input ram and graphcard get a value assigned)

PHP.

```
include_once 'databaseconn.php';

$ramResult = $_POST['ram'];
$graphcardResult = $_POST['graphcard'];
$processorResult = $_POST['processor'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM laptops WHERE ram = '$ramResult' AND graphcard = '$graphcardResult' AND processor = '$processorResult' ;"; 
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);  
$resultRows = [];
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $resultRows[] = $row;
        $nameResult = $row['name'];
        $ramResult = $row['ram'];
        $graphcardResult = $row['graphcard']; 
        $processorResult = $row['processor']; 
        $imgResult = $row['img'];  
        $imgId = $row['id'];
    }
}
```

This PHP query works if I already know which values are going to be defined. Since I do not know which are going to be defined and I don't want to look for a key with an empty value, I'm trying to find a way in order to only look for the values that are defined.

So far, I've found a way in order to store all the keys and values that are defined in an array.

```
$array = array();
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if (!empty($value)) {
        $array[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

Here's where the problem occurs: 
I'm struggling to find a way where I can get those keys and values that are defined and use them in the `$sql` query.

Ideally I want to get for each key and value and put it in the $sql query, like so:

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM laptops WHERE (foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)) => $key = $value;";
```

Note: names of the inputs (e.g. `name="ram"`) are the same as in the database:

```
id | ram | processor | graphcard | storage
1  |  2  |    i3     |     2     |   128
2  |  8  |    i7     |     4     |   512
3  |  4  |    i5     |  (empty)  |   512
```

Note: I'm aware of the injection. I'm trying to get this working before fixing it.

Comment: sql injection warning!!

Comment: @NigelRen I'm using mysqli

Comment: then use prepared statements

Comment: Yo have to test for the existance of each POST variable, and only use it if it exists

Comment: @delboy1978uk I know about the injection. I'm trying to get this working before using prepared statements

Comment: @RiggsFolly Do you have an example or source on how to do this?

Comment: _I'm trying to get this working before using prepared statements_ Does not compute !!! The difference between what you do to get a concatentated query working and a prepared query working is large. WHY DO IT TWICE? In short you wont do it

Comment: Its actually easier to do this to get a prepared statement to do this

Comment: @RiggsFolly I'm new to all this and trying to do it step by step. Do you have an example on how to do this with prepared statements? (not the injection part)

Comment: if you're new, use new stuff. ditch mysqli and use PDO. Here's EVERYTHING you need to know https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Comment: You could use the `OR` operator. If that is too simple and doesn't do the entire job, you could use what is called a CASE. Here's a tutorial on this: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-case-function/ - You could also use a subquery. A ternary operator also comes to mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code uses a prepared statement which is built from the fields in the POST array.  The idea is to build a couple of arrays, one with the `WHERE` part of the clause for each particular field, the other is the bind parameter value for the SQL.

You SHOULD ensure that the POST variables are 'reasonable' and so, this code has a list of the valid POST fields to use and extract only those that match (using `array_intersect_key()`)

The bound values are marked with a `?` in the SQL, and the value stored into `$bind`, these are linked to the statement using `bind_param()`.

```
$bind = [];
$where = [];
$type = "";
$validPost = ["ram", "graphcard", "storage"];
$postParams = array_intersect_key($_POST, array_flip($validPost));
foreach ($postParams as $key => $value) {
    if (!empty($value)) {
        $where[] = "{$key} = ?";
        $bind[] = $value;
        $type .= "s";
    }
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM laptops WHERE ".implode(" AND ", $where);

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param($type, ...$bind);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

Comment: I didn't expect this much. Thanks a lot Nigel. Much appreciated!!